# Stop the flashlight after pressing back

Tags: android, multithreading, android-camera

I am using a thread to run the flashlight and I want to stop that thread after the back is pressed.

I used the following code to start the thread:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Flashing...");
progressDialog.show();

thread = new Thread(MainActivity.this);
thread.start();
```

And the thread is doing:

```
public void run() {
    isOn = false;
    cam = Camera.open();
    p = cam.getParameters();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            if (isOn) {
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                Thread.sleep(pattern[i]);
                isOn = false;
            } else {
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                Thread.sleep(pattern[i]);
                isOn = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cam.release();
    handlerFinish.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

private Handler handlerFinish = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

I have tried this to stop, but there are only the progress dialog is dismissed but the flashlight is still working:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    cam.setParameters(p);
    isOn = false;
    thread.stop();
}
```

What can I do to achieve my goal (Stop the thread and flashlight after back is pressed)?

Comment: try  thread.join() while thread is running till it stops--ie wait till the thread stop and attempt to stop it in a while loop sorrunded with try catch once achived exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

try this loop to stop the thread

```
 boolean retry = true;

  while (retry) {

 try {

  thread.join();

   retry = false;

  } catch (InterruptedException e) {

  // try again shutting down the thread

  }

  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confuse. You mean I still use onBackPressed(), and add the above code into the thread to stop it?

Comment: yap you can use this inside on back pressed instead of thred.stop as intrupting a thread is bit triky you can reffer java join command for further details

Comment: I tried this, but the flashlight is still working. And it still working after the app is quit.